# Protractor: how to wait for full load of bootstrapped AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have a bootstrapped Angular (1.2.6) app. This means it doesn't have an explicit `ng-app`. As such, I've run into all sorts of problems getting Protractor framework'd tests to work (using SauceLabs and grunt-protractor-runner).

The errors vary based on what I try, but generally:

```
 Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://xxx:9000/ :
 angular never provided resumeBootstrap
```

Or...

```
Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}
```

I've found a few proposed solutions which I've tried. Including those found in [this rich thread](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/66), as well as [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/594), too. Nothing I do, though, gets things working.

I've tried to use `angular.resumeBootstrap` in the bootstrapping like so (note I tried multiple variations of this to no avail, including trying to set an ng-app programatically on the document body):

```
angular.element( document ).ready( function() {
  window.name = 'NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!'
  angular.bootstrap( document, [ 'app' ] );
  setTimeout( angular.resumeBootstrap, 0 );
});
```

The error for this, as others have found, is weird:

```
UnknownError: unknown error: [ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element
'<body ng-app="" ng-controller="ApplicationController" class=" ng-scope pace-done">'
```

What's weird/annoying is that, at least looking in Sauce Labs session, it appears that this test is working... it's just weirdly thinking that it's been bootstrapped twice.

I've also tried using various combinations of `waitForAngular`, `wait`, and others in the test itself. Here's one variation I've tried:

```
it( 'should load the home page', function() {
  ptor = protractor.getInstance();
  ptor.waitForAngular();
  ptor.driver.get( 'http://xxx:9000/' );
  ptor.driver.wait( function() {
    return ptor.getCurrentUrl().then( function() {
      return ptor.isElementPresent( by.id( 'signIn' ) ).then( function() {
        console.log('we are here!');
        return true;
      });
    });
  })
  .then( function() {
    expect( ptor.isElementPresent( by.id( 'signIn' ) ) ).toBe( true );
  });
});
```

This results in errors like the following:

```
1) e2e: home should load the home page
  Message: timeout: timed out after 20000 msec waiting for spec to complete
  Stacktrace: undefined
```

I've also tried increasing various timeouts in the config file to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @alecxe `grunt-protractor-runner@1.1.4` and `protractor@1.4.0`. I was running much earlier versions of both, upgraded (thinking that would help)... and no (noticeable) differences in errors.

Comment: I'm not sure this would help, but try downgrading protractor to earlier versions.

Comment: @alecxe yeah, previously was trying with `protractor@0.24.2` (!) and same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate the test in two 'it'-steps. Like this:

```
it( 'should load angular', function() {
  ptor = protractor.getInstance();
  ptor.waitForAngular();
})

it( 'should load the home page', function() {
  ptor.driver.get( 'http://xxx:9000/' );
  ptor.driver.wait( function() {
    return ptor.getCurrentUrl().then( function() {
      return ptor.isElementPresent( by.id( 'signIn' ) ).then( function()     {
        console.log('we are here!');
        return true;
      });
    });
  })
  .then( function() {
    expect( ptor.isElementPresent( by.id( 'signIn' ) ) ).toBe( true );
  });
});
```

The problem with protractor is that every command runs without waiting for the prior step to complete.  So, `ptor.waitForAngular()` and `ptor.driver.get( 'http://xxx:9000/' )` are running at almost the same time. If you separate these into two steps, protractor moves on after the first 'it'-step is done.

Comment: I forgot to mention that protrator.getInstance() is deprecated. Use browser instead https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1

Comment: This worked for me for my manually bootstrapped app using require.js. I put a precursor "it" block with just browser.waitForAngular() and set browser.ignoreSynchronization = true in my protractor conf file. It seems hacky, but it's working. phew.

Comment: Correction, this only works for me *some of the time*. Very frustrating, I still get intermittent errors with the exact same test.

Comment: This is because "browser.ignoreSynchronization = true" will cause protractor to ignore Angular's $timeout and $http calls, which will cause flaky test results. Use "ignoreSynchronization" with care.

Comment: I don't understand how this works - shouldn't the waitForAngular() be called AFTER calling the URL?

Comment: `it` blocks in tests should be independent from each other as the order they run is not guaranteed. Hence this approach might works sometimes, sometimes not.